# How can I use ffmpeg.net in my winfoms(c#)?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I use [ffmpeg.net](http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/).

How can I use this dll in my project for converting video or audio to another video/audio format ?
(I need a sample c# code for using this class library.)

I upload source code in below link :

> http://www.mediafire.com/?15spbnd5bopuja9

Comment: As I see it, ffmpegdotnet isn't ready for use yet???

Comment: Are you sure ? You check source code ? You can't get me a sample demo code for use it ?

Comment: From the HOME PAGE of the site: "The following are currently in the TODO list: Encoding support"; you have to have ENCODING if you want to CONVERT your audio/video, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use ffmpeg.exe directly. I have i.e done so to generate an image automatically when a videofile is uploaded to our cms system.

Please check out this blog (not mine): http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/